# REST API return entire queried JSON

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, rest, yaml

I do maintain an small REST API (SpringBoot) offering services to obtain data about ticketing from a small sized retailer. i.e.: you can send a request in order to get some information from a certain ticket (which has unique ID); the JSON response consists of a selection of fields from the unique ticket (which is stored as an unique document in Mongo DB).

Let say the API receives a request, then it would execute a query to Mongo DB, and then apply a projection to parse the queried data into a data model class, which in turn is finally parsed to a response JSON like, i.e.:

```
{
    "ticketData": {
        "retailerId": "023",
        "ticketId": "09834723469324",
        "ticketDate": "2021-06-20"
    },
    "buyerData": {
        "buyerId": "LN4382"
    }
}
```

Well, I am now required to return the entire queried JSON (that is, a JSON containing the whole ticket information, that has a lot of fields). ¿Is there any way to achieve this without creating a data model class with tens or hundreds of properties to match the stored ticket JSON? Even if I specify the API response using YAML and then use a codegen tool, is a lot of tedious work, and whenever the ticket JSON format evolves, I would need to change my DAO and response.

I just would like to send the original Mongo stored JSON and hand it back to the API client. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You should be able to just return the whole JSON as `String`…

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Jackson ObjectMapper which Spring already uses to serialize and deserialize JSON.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public HelloWorldController(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/jsonList")
    public ResponseEntity<List<JsonNode>> getJsonList() {
        List<String> data = List.of("{\"number\": 1}",
                "{\"number\": 2}",
                "{\"number\": 3}");
        List<JsonNode> nodes = toJsonNodeList(data);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(nodes);
    }

    private List<JsonNode> toJsonNodeList(List<String> strings) {
        List<JsonNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : strings) {
            try {
                JsonNode node = this.objectMapper.readTree(s);
                nodes.add(node);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
            }
        }
        return nodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Alexej Timonin , I will offer some feedback soon.